# XML value contains xml characters

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Actually an XML is passed as a value of Input XML attribute. Please help to fetch the XML value using XSLT 1.0

```
<Root>
<Element1 ProductDetails="<Input xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Amount="15632" Product="Pencil"></Input>"/>
</Root>
```

I need to just fetch the value of *ProductDetails* attribute.
i.e. only the below part using XSLT 1.0

```
<Input xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Amount="15632" Product="Pencil"></Input>
```

Comment: The XML sample you have posted is not actually well-formed. The XML in the attribute would need to be escaped (i.e. By using `&gt;`, `&lt;` and `&quot;`). Additionally, the closing `</Element1>` should not be there as it has already been self-closed. Does your XML really look like that, or has it actually been properly escaped? Thanks!

Comment: The input XML is systematically generated as I posted. The below solution doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: If that is the case, then you can't use XSLT on it, as that only works on well-formed XML. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh4h. On the otherhand, if the XML in the attribute was properly escaped, you could potentially use `xsl:value-of` with `disable-output-escaping`. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh4h/1

Comment: As Tim has already pointed out, that attribute value with unescaped XML breaks all XML syntax rules for well-formedness so you have no chance to process it with any XML parser or XML tool. You will need to fix the process of generating that markup or you will need to look into processing the input with some error correcting parser that swallows that syntax. Depending on your platform and XSLT processor you might then be able to plug in that parser instead of the normal XML parser or you need to preprocess the input to convert it to well-formed XML.

Comment: If you don't have XML, you cannot use XML tools.

Answer (score -1):

check it:-

```
<xsl:value-of select="@ProductDetails"/>
```

Comment: @Tim Stack this answer was ask only get value of attribute value of ProductDetails. After my answer user edit Question what can i do?